# Node.js custom Module

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run `app.js`, I get this error:

```
MBPdiDaniele3:Desktop danielemartini$ node app.js 
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
MBPdiDaniele3:Desktop danielemartini$
```

Here's the code for `make_request.js`:

```
var http = require('http');

var makeRequest = function(message) {

    var options = {
        host: 'localhost', port: 8080, path:'/', method: 'POST'
    }

    var request = http.request(options, function(response) {
        response.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
    request.write(message);
    request.end();
};
module.exports = makeRequest;
```

Here's the code for `app.js`:

```
var makeRequest = require('./make_request');

makeRequest("Here's looking at you, kid");
makeRequest("Hello, this is dog");
```

Comment: And... What's your question?

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't have anything listening on port 8080.

Comment: Make sure no other services are running port 8080 (Tomcat or a previous version of your service.)

Comment: Make sure something **IS** running on port 8080 since that's what you are connecting to

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible causes :

1. No service is running on localhost:8080
2. A service runs on 8080 which refuses connections actively.

To check what is running, use one of those 2 commands (Unix) :

- `lsof -i :8080 -S`
- `netstat -a | grep 8080`

3 - Your running service isn't bound to your internal IP.

I've encountered the issue a few times on Cloud servers, where localhost/127.0.0.1 are not recognized. Try using the external IP of your machine (and make sure the firewall lets you make requests), or force your service to bind to all interfaces.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not an answer this is guessing and general debugging instructions

Comment: @Jarrod_Roberson: This may not be the answer but it is helpful and therefore useful.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Isn't Stack Overflow about helping users? There are 3 possible answers to this question, and following my informations should help OP solve his problem. If anything, the question may need to be rewritten to include 'I've tried this and that', therefore removing the guessing element.